# Is it possble to boot a Windows XP HDD with a different computer?

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, boot, quark

I have 2 NON OEM computers. One has a proprietary software installed (I believe it binds with the IP address and the computer name while online Activation). Now the computer with this proprietary software crashed. The company selling this software charges huge amount for reactivation.

Can I use the crashed computer's HDD to boot into new computer? So my activation remains intact? I can reinstall drivers and do registry clean-up as required. All I want to do is Use my licensed software on the new computer without reactivation.

Please note this software generates an installation code for every new installation and you have to provide this code to the comapany to get an Activation code for the new installation.

Comment: If you tell the company that the only computer you had for running the software crashed, they will most probably let you reactivate on a new one. Things like that happen all the time.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to answer this question with yes or no, sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't. Wouldn't it be much more efficient to replace the broken hardware in the first computer with the hardware of the second (or buy new hw)?

Answer (score 1):

If the hardware is too different it will bluescreen when you attempt to boot it and will corrupt the installation and may not boot in the original system after doing this.

Best thing to do is install the drive in the other PC, do a XP repair install before you ever attempt to boot the system. A repair will strip out all the drivers, then you can boot into windows and install the correct motherboard drivers.

[See this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/824125), go to the "Replace a failed motherboard" section for the XP repair procedure.

Note: the XP install cd you use to do the repair Must be the same service pack level as the installed OS you are trying to repair, slipstream the appropriate SP into the XP cd if needed.

Answer (score 0):

On my oppinion you may have two problems:
1 - If your Bios is AHCI and your Windows was installed over IDE, you will have problems on boot. (This would'nt be a impeditive problem because you can change settings on Bios of even on Windows registry. [look here](http://www.vistax64.com/general-discussion/271218-switch-ahci-ide-tutorial-howto.html))

2- Your Video / Audio / Ethernet / Wifi drivers may not be compatible with your new hardware and your Windows XP will not boot up. You can also resolve this if you have the new machine drivers on a pen-drive. You can install it on the old one machine and then change your hdd to the new one.

Summarizing, on my oppinion, you should have some manageable problems and it will be possible.